# Angular2 shared observable

Tags: reactjs, angular, typescript, reactive-programming, rxjs

Doing some experimentation with Angular2 and curious about how to solve a situation where a service exposes a shared observable. Where one component is responsible for getting the data and another is responsible for displaying the data. Here is some code:

The common HttpService responsible for getting the data

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class Service {

  subject = new Subject<string[]>;

  observable$ = this.subject.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  observable: Observable<string[]>;

  get(link: string): Observable<string[]> {
    this.observable$ = this.http.get('myapi.com')
                    .map((res: Response) => this.subject.next(res.json())
                    .catch(this.handleError);

    return this.observable$;
  }

  /**
    * Handle HTTP error
    */
  private handleError (error: any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

The GetComponent responsible for getting the data

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

import { Service } from '../shared/index';


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'get',
  templateUrl: 'get.component.html',
  providers: [Service],
})
export class GetComponent {

  constructor(public service: Service) {}

  submit() {
    this.service.get(this.url).subscribe();
  }
}
```

The DisplayComponent responsible for displaying the data

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'display',
  templateUrl: 'display.component.html'
})
export class DisplayComponent {
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(public service: Service) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // the observable is undefined :(
    this.subscription = this.service.observable$.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error => {
      // this never gets reached :(
    })
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    // prevent memory leak when component is destroyed
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

This design works ok except the error handling does not work for the `DisplayComponent`. Also the map function in the `HttpService` doesn't seem quite right `this.subject.next(res.json()`

Also it doesn't seem quite right that the GetComponent has to "subscribe" like this `this.service.get(this.url).subscribe();`

What is the proper way to design this sort of thing? How can I get the `DisplayComponent` to observe errors thrown by the `HttpComponent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several problems where Service.$observable is modified several times:

```
observable$ = this.subject.asObservable();
this.observable$ = this.http.get('myapi.com') .... // remove this line
```

The right way to do this:
`Get Component` calls `Service` to get data. After data is loaded, `Get Component` emits a `Data Ready` event with the data. `Display Component`, and other components that use this data, listen to `DataReady` event and update data when the event is emitted.

Code to explain my answer:

```
@Injectable()
export class GetService {
  /// subject
  subject = new Subject<string[]>()

  /// the observable
  observable = this.subject.asObservable()


  constructor(private $http: Http) {

  }

  /// get data
  getData() {
    // not override observable here
    this.$http.get("api.com")
      .map(response => response.json()) // map the data
      .subscribe((data: string[]) => this.subject.next(data), // emit data event
              error => this.subject.error(error)) // emit error event
  }
}
```

Comment: Events? I wanted to use RxJS.

Comment: Yeah, your code is right apart from you modify $observable from `this.subject.asObservable()` to `this.http.get('myapi.com')` and you don't redirect the error to `this.subject.asObservable()`

Comment: oh i tried to do ```this.subject.error(error)``` in the HttpService catch function. Can you add some code to your answer for the proposed solution?

Comment: I also tried to just do return this.http.get('myapi.com') rather than resetting this.observable$ which was probably a bad idea

Comment: So you are saying I should return a Subscription rather than an Observable?

Comment: In `getData` you return nothing. You wait until the data is ready then you forward the event using subject. From other place you will use observable to subscribe for the data.

Comment: Ok that seems like an ok solution. The only issue is that now if the GetComponent did one day want to use that observable it would not be chainable. It would have to use the HttpService observable$

Comment: Then you can use this.subject.asObservable() instead of observable.